# How to fix this text problem in mail newsletter?

Tags: css, email

The text of every rss in the newsletter is going down and positioned to the left.

I tried to change to put two columns in order to avoid it, but then i'm couldn't get to change the column size and the text wrap down in mobile version.

```html
<div style="text-align: left;">
     <a href="https://contratocompraventavehiculo.co">
          <img data-file-id="798535" height="60" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fb081e42ac85d682d4bbec/images dd-8a84-47cd-b3e0-a23f612be.png" style="border: 0px  ; width: 60px; height: 60px; float: left; margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;" width="60" /> 
     </a>
     <span style="font-family:open sans,helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif">
          <span style="font-size:16px">
               <span style="color:#000000">
                    Become an expert
               </span>
               <br />
               <a href="https://contratocompraventavehiculo.co" target="_blank"> 
                    <span style="color:#000000">
                         <strong>Discover new opportunities</strong>
                    </span>
               </a>
          </span>
     </span>
</div>
```

In the next link you can view that the text is going down and not aligned with the first part of text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wczPJ.png

Comment: Please format your code and don't copy & paste such a spaghetti code :)
Make also sure to provide a working example. Next to the image icon in the editor you can paste in your code to get and save a live preview.

Comment: For emailers you should be using tabular approch rather than div based structure still if you want to use this structure only please give fiddle link.

Comment: Your text is wrapping, and the second (wrapped) line is going below the image to the left. As Omkar says, you cannot use `<div>`s with email layout, only tables.

Comment: I'm very new with code and i was trying to make it work with some advices of stackoverflow but without lucky. Also i search to how to implement tables in mailchimp rss as said @gibberish but i couldn't find info, how i can make that the rss item text wrapper not goes to the left and keps aligned with the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML code has changed a lot from how it started out 20 years ago.

At the beginning (20 years ago), we made tables. Tables for everything. These days we use `<div>` tags and `<aside>` tags - but back then, everything was in a table structure. To position things precisely, we put `<tables>` inside `<table>` cells. That is what you must still do - for emails only.:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table><tr><td>some data</td></tr></table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Also, tables in email support only limited CSS. And your CSS cannot be inside `<style>` tags - it must be inline, like this:

```
<td style="text-align:right">
```

Not like this:

```
<style>
    td{text-align:right;}
</style>
```

#### References:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/

https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-coding/step-step-guide-create-html-email/